# Why this snippet thows NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my code sinipped

```
public void testThread() throws Exception {
    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ExecutorService checkPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
        checkPool.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                list.add("abc");
            }
        });
    }
    checkPool.shutdown();
    try {
        checkPool.awaitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

I run this on junit test but it throws NullPointerException at

```
System.out.println(list.get(i).toString());
```

I have no idea why this happened!

Comment: The problem is, `List` and `ArrayList` are NOT thread safe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have race condition when you perform `add()` on your `list`.

When you run `execute()`, there are no guarantees as to when the `Runnable` object's `run()` method will actually run.

To prevent this you need to use the `synchronized` keyword in order to lock access to `list`:

```
public void run() {
    synchronized (list) {
        list.add("abc");
    }
}
```

Comment: or `final List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());` +1 for actually diagnosing the problem rather then stating the obvious...

Comment: I understand it, the `ArrayList` is unsafed while multithreading,thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes, but one must stress that synchronized collections must be used with caution, since each individual method is synchronized, but problems start to arise when you have multiple threads doing different things to a synchronized collection in between collection method calls. So all in all, it's important not to dismiss `synchronized` on multi-threaded scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Because probably `list.get(i)` returns `null` and then you call `.toString()` on `null`. You should check with your debugger what's inside `list` when you iterate over it.

More specifically, it should throw an exception when you reach `i == list.size()`

Comment: Hi,I can understand you idea, but I am just confused where the null element comes from and I didn't put null element into the list

Comment: This describes the effect, but not the core problem, WHY are some of the elements `null`...

Answer (score 0):

Native Junit test method doesn't support the multithreading test, because when Junit test method finished will call the System.exit, so the threads will be stop. Maybe this is the reason you can't get string from your list.

But you can use the [GroboUntils](http://groboutils.sourceforge.net/) to test multithreading, some example as follow will tell you how to use:

```
@Test
public void MultiRequestsTest() {
    TestRunnable runner = new TestRunnable() { 
        @Override
        public void runTest() throws Throwable {
            // to write your test case here      
        }
    };

    int runnerCount = 100;
    TestRunnable[] trs = new TestRunnable[runnerCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < runnerCount; i++) {
        trs[i] = runner;
    }

    MultiThreadedTestRunner mttr = new MultiThreadedTestRunner(trs);
    try {
        mttr.runTestRunnables();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```